# PHP: Converting words/strings to numbers and add them up

Tags: php, sum, addition

1. I have a form in which I want to type any combination of words, followed by a submit.
2. Let's say I type "**bababa ba**"
3. This has to become "**2+1+2+1+2+1+2+1 =12**"
4. Folloed by: **12 = 1+2 = 3** The answer always has to be broken down below 10. The 3 is the only answer I want to see.

A total beginner, for weeks I've been messing around with `$let_arr = ["a" => "1", "b" => "2",];`, `str_split`, `explode`, and everything else. Can't figure it out.

Ayone who can help me underway? maybe the insights will help me further along.

Comment: Learn PHP and do it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Letters are numbers in fact - they have an ordinal ASCII value which can be retrieved by `ord()`. For example, `ord('a')` is 97. So, you don't need an array as look-up table for this.

First, let us strip all non-letter characters from the string and convert everything to lowercase (since `ord('a') != ord('A')`):

```
$str = 'bababa ba';
$letters = preg_replace('~[^a-z]~i', '', $str); // remove all non-alpha characters
$letters = strtolower($letters); // convert to lowercase
```

Now let's sum the single letters up:

```
$sum = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($letters); $i++)
{
    $sum += ord($letters[$i]) - 96; // 96 == ord('a') - 1
}
```

At last, we have to get the digit sum:

```
$ds = 0;
while ($sum != 0)
{
    $ds += $sum % 10;         // extract and add last digit
    $sum = (int) ($sum / 10); // remove last digit
}
```

Now, `$ds` will contain your result. I hope, this is what you asked for.

Comment: That's some incredible coding. But an array might be necessary. Have to study it longer (didn't see any output appear yet). Only 9 numbers to designate all alphabet letters. This was my old array: `$letters = array ('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5, 'f' => 6, 'g' => 7, 'h' => 8, 'i' => 9, 'j' => 1, 'k' => 2, 'l' => 3, 'm' => 4, 'n' => 5, 'o' => 6, 'p' => 7, 'q' => 8, 'r' => 9, 's' => 1, 't' => 2, 'u' => 3, 'v' => 4, 'w' => 5, 'x' => 6, 'y' => 7, 'z' => 8)];`

Comment: You can do that without an array too: `sum += ((ord($letters[$i]) - 96) % 9) + 1;` It's just some maths. If you want output to appear, append a final line: `echo $ds;`

Answer (score 0):

To find out that a=1 and b=2 and ... this simple form/function:
You can try this "simple" code here: http://wistudat.be/try/calcuword.php

```
<form action="./calcuword.php" onsubmit="" method="post"> 
<b>Enter your word: </b>
<br> 
<input type="text" name="word">
<br> 
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
<p style="color:red;">

<?php 

$word= filter_var($_POST['word'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
echo "String : ".$word ." to integer : ";

function CtoI($alfa)
{
$array = array_flip(range(a, z));
return $array[$alfa] + 1;
}

$chars = str_split($word);
foreach($chars as $char){
if($word){
echo CtoI($char);
if ($char === end($chars)){
echo "=";
}
else{
echo "+";
}

} //End if($word)
} //End foreach

?>
```